# Can anyone help me on this Download Jquery Datatable data in Excel and PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am very new to jQuery and need to implement the data download functionality in Excel and PDF from JQuery Datatable.

The Datatable is implemented already and in that only I need to implement the download data functionality.

I googled it but was unable to find good articles to explain things in better perspective.

Below is the code for reference.

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered" data-table-name="pqe-contact-dom"></table>
```

In HTML we are using data-table-name=**"pqe-contact-dom"** to populate the data into the table, and the datatable code is written in JS file.

**JS File Code:**

```
var reportFunction = function(code) {   
    $.ajax({
                type : 'get',
                url : url,
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(data) {
                var reportArray = new Array();
                    var reportArrayLen = data.length;


                    for (var l = 0; l < reportArrayLen; l++) {

                            reportArray[l] = new Array();
                            var code = data[l].CODE;
                            var name = data[l].NAME;
                            var e_name = data[l].E_Name;
                            var e_phone = data[l].E_Phone;
                            var e_email = data[l].E_eMail;


                            reportArray[l][0]= supplier_code;
                            reportArray[l][1] = supplier_name;
                            reportArray[l][2] = e_name;
                            reportArray[l][3] = e_phone;
                            reportArray[l][4] = e_email;

                        }   
                        var reportArrayVar = reportArray;
                        gotoReport( reportArrayVar ); //Calling below the function that  datatable and     //passing data array to populate data
                },
                error : function() {
                    alert("ajax error");
                }
                    });

};


//This function will populate the data to the datatable

function gotoReport(reportArrayVar){    

require( [ 'jquery', 'datatables', 'prettify', 'bootstrap'], function(jQuery) 
{ jQuery('table[data-table-name="nonqmreports-dt"]').DataTable(
/* options */{
    //useFloater : false


                useFloater : false,
                'aoColumns' : [ 
                {'sTitle' : 'Code', 'sClass' : 'essential'}, //essential
                {'sTitle' : 'Name ', 'sClass' : 'optional' },
                {'sTitle' : 'E Name', 'sClass' : 'essential'},
                {'sTitle' : 'E Phone', 'sClass' : 'essential'},
                {'sTitle' : 'E eMail ', 'sClass' : 'optional' }

                ],
                'aaData': reportArrayVar,
                'bProcessing': true,
                'isResponsive' : true,
                 'bDestroy': true,
                  'bRetrieve': false,
                'bPaginate':true,
                // 'bStateSave': true,
                 'bInfo': true,
                'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers'


})
});
```

}

In this I need to implement the data download to Excel and PDF functionality, but I am unclear how to do that.  Can anyone help me understand how to go about it?

Comment: Getting error while adding anything into this. I have added this but     "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        } but getting error even tried to add buttons but not working

Answer (score 0):

First things first,
this should be present in your JS Code [ignore the tags in Quotes]

```
"dom": '<"pad5"CT><"clear"><lf<"clear">r<t>ip>',<br>
tableTools: {
  "sSwfPath": "assets/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
}
```

next you need have this file.
copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf [make sure path is according to the html/php file where  is initialized]

next check the console f12 for errors and post the errors.
and mention your DataTable version and Jquery Version mine is latest
enjoy

Comment: Hi Rohit thanks for your answer but I tried adding "sSwfPath": "assets/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" but it was giving error. can you please brief it using the same code which I have mentioned in my question that would be helpful

Comment: and see that you have this file present "assets/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" if not then it will be giving an error on console of your browser

Answer (score 0):

First find the local path of  **"copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"** file inside your TableTool plugin folder and use the same path for **"sSwfPath:"** like I have mentioned below:

```
require(['jquery', 'datatables', 'prettify', 'bootstrap'], function (jQuery) {
    jQuery('table[data-table-name="nonqmreports-dt"]').DataTable(
    /* options */
    {
        //useFloater : false

        useFloater: false,
            'aoColumns': [{
            'sTitle': 'Code',
            'sClass': 'essential'
        }, //essential
        {
            'sTitle': 'Name ',
            'sClass': 'optional'
        }, {
            'sTitle': 'E Name',
            'sClass': 'essential'
        }, {
            'sTitle': 'E Phone',
            'sClass': 'essential'
        }, {
            'sTitle': 'E eMail ',
            'sClass': 'optional'
        }

        ],
            'aaData': reportArrayVar,
            'bProcessing': true,
            'isResponsive': true,
            'bDestroy': true,
            'bRetrieve': false,
            'bPaginate': true,
        // 'bStateSave': true,
        'bInfo': true,
        `enter code here`
            'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
            "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "/Scripts/TableTools-2.2.0/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" // path where swf files is located.
        }
    })
});
```